# For all real numbers satisfying $a < b$ , there exists an $n ∈ N$ such that $a + 1/n < b$

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

> For all real numbers satisfying $a < b$ , there exists an $n ∈ N$ such that
>   $a + 1/n < b$.

My try:

Contradiction: For all real numbers satisfying $a < b$ and any $n ∈ N$;
$a + 1/n \ge b$.

Then $1/n \ge b - a$, then  $n \le \frac{1}{b-a}$, take $n = \frac{1}{k(b-a)}$, where $k ∈ N$, then $a + \frac{1}{1/k(b-a)} < b$ => $a(1-k)<b(1-k)$ => $a>b$, since $1-k<0$ for all defined $k$, but $k = 1$ then I recieve $0<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice of $n$ is not correct. It need not even be an integer. Take $n= [\frac 1 {b-a}]+1$ where $[.]$ is the floor function. [ Note that $n >\frac 1 {b-a}$ .(I have added $1$ to $[\frac 1 {b-a}]$ to make sure that I get strict inequality). Now $a+\frac 1 n <a+(b-a)=b$ and this is what we want].

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate. If I take $n = [1/(b-a)] + 1$ how does it help me to show the contradiction that I wrote? And why $+1$? Why $n = [1/(b-a)]$ is not sufficient?

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan See  my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You May argue directly without using a proof by contradiction.
By the properties of the reals there is some integer $n>\frac1{b-a}$. Thus $a+\frac1n<a+(b-a)=b$.

Comment: I tried not to use it here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your proof. You said take $n = \frac{1}{k(b-a)}$. How did you find the $k$ such that $n$ is an integer, besides $k$ is an integer too? It is not possible at all.

For example $b = \pi$ and $a = e$ (nepper number). How did you find such $k$ that $n = \frac{1}{k(\pi - e)}$ will be integer too? You can find the problem here.

Comment: I saw it. Thank you.

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

An option:

We have $b-a >0$, $a,b$ real, and let $n, n_0$ be positive integers

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } (1/n) =0$:

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given:

There is a $n_0 >0$, s.t. for $n \ge n_0$

$|1/n|  \lt |1/n_0| \lt \epsilon$.

Choose $\epsilon \lt (b-a)$.

Then

$1/n_0 \lt \epsilon = (b-a)$,  or

$a +1/n_0 < b$.